# Why Linux kernel LSM_HOOK macro is defined with many parameters?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-security-module

In Linux kernel, the `LSM_HOOK` usage is like:

```
LSM_HOOK(int, 0, binder_set_context_mgr, const struct cred *mgr)
LSM_HOOK(int, 0, binder_transaction, const struct cred *from,
     const struct cred *to)
LSM_HOOK(int, 0, binder_transfer_binder, const struct cred *from,
     const struct cred *to)
LSM_HOOK(int, 0, binder_transfer_file, const struct cred *from,
     const struct cred *to, struct file *file)
LSM_HOOK(int, 0, ptrace_access_check, struct task_struct *child,
     unsigned int mode)
LSM_HOOK(int, 0, ptrace_traceme, struct task_struct *parent)
LSM_HOOK(int, 0, capget, struct task_struct *target, kernel_cap_t *effective,
     kernel_cap_t *inheritable, kernel_cap_t *permitted)
LSM_HOOK(int, 0, capset, struct cred *new, const struct cred *old,
     const kernel_cap_t *effective, const kernel_cap_t *inheritable,
     const kernel_cap_t *permitted)
LSM_HOOK(int, 0, capable, const struct cred *cred, struct user_namespace *ns,
     int cap, unsigned int opts)
```

The `LSM_HOOK` is defined as:

```
struct security_hook_heads {
    #define LSM_HOOK(RET, DEFAULT, NAME, ...) struct hlist_head NAME;
    #include "lsm_hook_defs.h"
    #undef LSM_HOOK
} __randomize_layout;
```

In this situation, parameters except for `NAME` are all discarded. I am curious why the macro expansion needs so many arguments like above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the macro `LSM_HOOK` has different implementations in various subsystem or modules, as you can see, in the struct, it `undef` the macro immediately after usage, so in this particular module, the remaining arguments are not needed and ignored.
But let's look at another module, e.g. in `bpf_lsm.h`, it defines `LSM_HOOK` like this:

```
#define LSM_HOOK(RET, DEFAULT, NAME, ...) \
    RET bpf_lsm_##NAME(__VA_ARGS__);
#include <linux/lsm_hook_defs.h>
#undef LSM_HOOK
```

where the extra arguments are passed into the `bpf_lsm_...` functions.
So this kind of macro provides extensibility and flexibility among different modules.